# NSDictionary Vs. NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am reading on objective-c (a nerd ranch book), and I can't help thinking about this question: How do I decide which collection type, NSArray or NSDictionary (both with or w/o their mutable subclasses), to use when reading content from URL?

Let's say am reading JSON data from a PHP script (a scenario am dealing with), which to use? I know it is stated in many references that it depends on structure of data (i.e. JSON), but could a clear outline of the two structures be outlined?

Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 10):

`NSArray` is basically just an ordered collection of objects, which can be accessed by index.

 `NSDictionary` provides access to its objects by key(typically NSStrings, but could be any object type like hash table).

To generate an object graph from a JSON string loaded via a URL, you use `NSJSONSerialization`, which generates an Objective-C object structure. The resulting object depends on the JSON string. If the top-level element in your JSON is an array (starts with **`"["`**), you'll get an NSArray. If the top-level element is a JSON object (starts with **`"{"`**), you'll get an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `NSArray` when ever you have a collection of the same type of objects, and `NSDictionary` when you have attributes on an object.

If you have, lets say a `person` object containing a `name`, a `phone number` and an `email` you would put it in a dictionary.

Doing so allows the order of the values to be random, and gives you a more reliable code.

If you want  to have more then one person you can then put the person objects in an array.

Doing so allow you to iterate the user objects.

Comment: Disagree - what if you want to lookup `Customer` objects by their telephone number? There are plenty of valid reasons for dictionaries holding homogenous objects.

Comment: I would request you to highlight your point with pseudo or sample code to be clear about your answer

Comment: @CarlVeazey of course there are cases where you have specific needs. By using arrays you can create a more general backend, that can extract data from a database and create JSON for you.

Answer (score 0):

"withContentOfURL" or "withContentOfFile" requires the data in the URL or the file to be in a specific format as it is required by Cocoa. JSON is *not* that format. You can only use these methods if you wrote the data to the file or the URL yourself in the first place, with the same data. If you write an NSArray, you can read an NSArray. If you write an NSDictionary, you can read an NSDictionary. Everything else will fail.