# NSDictionary vs NsArray

Tags: objective-c

I was asked in an interview what structure I would use to store 100 names: an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` and why.

What is the best answer?

He said he wants to figure out whether a name exists.

Comment: Did they not give you any more information than that?  How it's to be used?  How the names will be looked up?  Sorted?  What the names represent?

Comment: Well, which is the most efficient? Which is the least memory-consuming? How will you need to access the names later on? Will you need the names to be sorted for easy lookup?

Comment: If he wants to figure out whether a name exists then the correct answer would be "NSSet".

Comment: I found a similar question with answers. I hope it helps you! Article:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643237/nsdictionary-vs-nsarray

Comment: (You should have engaged him in a discussion of the required features, and the various merits of the two classes.)

Comment: If it's just existence that's wanted, and you have to choose either NSArray or NSDictionary, then use NSDictionary. But as Hot Licks points out, NSSet is more appropriate for this requirement.

Comment: @HotLicks and why is an nsset better than an array or dictionary?

Comment: If all you want to know is whether something's in the "list", it answers that question very efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

This is an open ended question, and the interviewer is probably more interested in your thought process and the questions you ask. The short answer IMO is NSArray if you just need to enumerate objects. NSDictionary if you need to lookup objects by a key. And NSSet when you just need to check membership. Of course this all varies depending on the amount of items, and how they are being used. With 100 items, it is probably 6 one, 1/2 dozen the other. And more a matter of readability and understandability in the code.

Read this old, but not outdated article for an excellent look at the performance considerations of each collection. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html

Comment: The mentioned article only tests data structures for a given size, for a more in depth analysis of NSArrays read http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this has some good explanations of the two even though it's more focused on the performance aspect https://stackoverflow.com/a/10545362/1415348

It's really ends up being more open ended b/c it depends on what you might want to do with the data.

And now that it's edited with more info about how they want to use it I'd agree with Hot Licks, NSSet would be best for that. It has the method containsObject to determine existence in the set. [NSSet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is to ask more questions to clarify the requirements. 
What kind of names?
What languages and locales?
How will they be used? 
Will they change or be static?
Is there a storage or performance concern?
And so on.

In all likelihood the goal was to find out how you think about design. 
Even if they didn't answer further questions they probably expected at least some reasoning provided for using various data structures where you illustrate how they can be used and why they make sense.

I seriously doubt they expected a one word response